# Listbox on one page calling SelectionChanged event handler of ListBox on AnotherPage?

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, windows-phone-7

I have a two pages say `Main.xaml` and `Details.xaml`.Each page has a ListBox and I am setting each of it to a collection in ViewModel(Same collection).The strange thing is that when i select an item in Details page it calls the `SelectionChanged` event handler on `Main` page and `Details` page.Is this a bug?

I have solved the problem by unhooking `SelectionChanged` eventhandler in `OnNavigatedFrom`() method.

**EDIT**

In Main.Xaml I have something like below:

```
<ListBox Name="MainDataListBox" Margin="8,113,8,8" ItemsSource="{Binding DataList}" SelectionChanged="MainDataListBox_SelectionChanged">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"   >
                            <Border BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="#A5FFFFFF" Width="80" Margin="0,20,0,20" Height="60">
                                <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl, Mode=OneWay}"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="80" Height="60" Stretch="Fill" />
                            </Border>
                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="40" FontWeight="Normal" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="30,0,0,0" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
              </ListBox>
```

In Details.xaml also I have same kind of ListBox:

```
<ListBox Name="DetailDataListBox" Margin="8,113,8,8" ItemsSource="{Binding DataList}" SelectionChanged="DetailDataListBox_SelectionChanged">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"   >
                            <Border BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="#A5FFFFFF" Width="80" Margin="0,20,0,20" Height="60">
                                <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl, Mode=OneWay}"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="80" Height="60" Stretch="Fill" />
                            </Border>
                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="40" FontWeight="Normal" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="30,0,0,0" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
              </ListBox>
```

Both of the Pages Main and Details have seperate EvenHandlers `MainDataListBox_SelectionChanged` and `DetailDataListBox_SelectionChanged`.

The problem is when i select an Item in Details Page `MainDataListBox_SelectionChanged` is called first and then `DetailDataListBox_SelectionChanged`.
Also my viewmodel is a static one in App.cs and I am setting the data context of both these pages to same viewmodel.

Thanks and Regards

vaysage

Comment: sounds like you're hooking both lists up to the same event. Without seing code it'd be hard to say for sure though.

Comment: @Matt Lacey I am hooking the both lists to seperate events.

Comment: can you post some code which demonstrates how to reproduce this.

Comment: @Matt Lacey i have added the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As both listsboxes were bound to the same dataset a change in the selected time in one list would have affected the other.

Obviosuly you're found a work around but I'd recommend having a unique view model for each page. If the page is just a different way of displaying the same data use a single page and alter the display as appropriate. (Creating your own visual states may be a good way to do this.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.can you please post a link for "Creating your own visual states " if possible ,because I am entirely new to this idea.Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Vaysage try starting with this: http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/justinangel/archive/2008/12/25/custom-vsm-visualstatemanagers-in-silverlight-2-0.aspx